# Browser Navigation with Flask and ngRoute

Tags: python, angularjs, flask, ngroute

I have a single page AngularJS app that uses ngRoute with Python Flask as a backend.  My problem is that when I navigate to a URL through the app, everything works fine -- but if I try to refresh that page, or navigate to that route directly, I get a 404 error.

For example, if I navigate to the help page (localhost:5000/help) through the app, I get:

```
GET /partials/help.html HTTP/1.1 200-
```

But if I open a new tab and enter in a URL of localhost:5000/help, I get:

```
GET help HTTP/1.1 - 404
```

I think the problem is in my directory structure (see below) and in how I am serving the initial route through Flask.  Here is the relevant part of my main.py:

```
app = Flask(__name__, static_url_path="")
api = Api(app)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return app.send_static_file('index.html')
```

Here are the relevant parts of my file structure:

```
Project_path  
 |-main.py
 |-static/
    |-index.html
    |-partials/    #Contains html templates routed to for views
    |-js/
      |-app.js     #Contains ngRoute logic for the app
      |-controllers/
      |-libs/
```

If it would be helpful to see the routes in app.js, just let me know and I will include them.

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated, as this is driving me absolutely crazy trying to figure it out

Comment: When you refresh, the URL in the browser bar will get requested from Flask. If you haven't defined a route that matches it, you will get a 404.

Comment: That makes sense.  So, how do I configure my Flask code so that I don't need to define every route on both the server-side as well as the client-side?